# Using theme to change icons in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, themes

So Microsoft has set out some documentation on [how to write .theme files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for windows 7 and (I assume that this applies) windows 8. In their documentation they point out that you can edit the registry's default values for different icons by using something similar to the following:

```
[CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\DefaultIcon]
DefaultValue=%ProgramFiles%\Fabrikam\Computer.ico
```

So I downloaded [a pre-made theme](http://www.deviantart.com/art/CLEAN-VS-for-8-1-511732617), followed a guide to patch my system, and installed the theme according to the steps laid out. After confirming that it was working, I tried to edit one of the icon values.

```
[CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\DefaultIcon]
DefaultValue=C:\Customization\Icons\Network.ico
```

Unfortunately, I saw no change to the icon. I also tried opening the registry using regedit and editing the values directly. However, even after taking control of a particular registry key, I was unable to edit or add new values.

So, is there a way of programmatically setting the values of the icons from a theme? Do I need to change the syntax I'm using? Do I need some special permission?